# Deploy multiple ASP.NET MVC sites on the same machine

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc

I already have an ASP.NET site running in my Windows Server 2003 (computer name: `myserver`), so whenever I want to access the site, I would just have to type `http://myserver`. The issue now is can I host another ASP.NET MVC site on that server 2003 machine? If yes, can I configure the url (`http://myserver2`?) so that I can access it?

**Edit: The Windows Server 2003 is hosting intranet application only. Which is my when they access my original ASP.NET site, they just need to specify `http://myserver` and that's it.**

Answer (score 3):

Set the host header of your website to myserver.  Then create another website in IIS and set the host header to myserver2.

Follow the instructions from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287 for more details.

You will need to add myserver2 to DNS to allow access to it, however you can add it to your hosts file for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean remotely or locally? If *remotely*, this is typically done through DNS -- so you'd have:

```
myserver.com     192.168.0.1
myserver2.com    192.168.0.1
```

This requires IIS to have appropriate host-headers configured for each site so when the incoming requests come in, IIS knows which website it should go to.

Alternately the classic one-site-per-ip-address way is

```
myserver.com     192.168.0.1
myserver2.com    192.168.0.2
```

But this becomes onerous and a bit wasteful unless you have hundreds of IPs sitting around doing nothing.

If I am misunderstanding you, and you want to use local only (vs worldwide) names, it's even simpler.